# Create a new Word document containing the selected content of the Google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am able to create a Word document with the full content of the Google document (referred [link](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8d639542577a594f6104b7f6fb753064)).
I need to create a new Word document in the drive with the selected content (selection only) of a Google document. Is there a way to achieve that?
I think if there is a way to get the blob for the selection of Google document content, with that blob I can achieve that. I browsed in web, but not found any supportive information.

**Code for convert the Google document into a word document :**

```
function convertGoogleDocToMicrosoftWordDoc(docId) {
  if (docId == null) throw new Error("No file ID.");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(docId);
  var mime = file.getMimeType();
  var format = "";
  var ext = "";
  switch (mime) {
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.document":
      format = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
      ext = ".docx";
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }

  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + docId + "/export?mimeType="+ format;
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getBlob();
  var filename = file.getName();

  var id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName(~filename.indexOf(ext) ? filename : filename + ext).getId();
  return id;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be:

1. Copy the selection you want from the original document to a temporary document.
2. Pass the ID of the new document to the function `convertGoogleDocToMicrosoftWordDoc()`
3. Delete the temporal document

###### `Code.gs`

```js
function convertGoogleDocToMicrosoftWordDoc(docId) {
  if (docId == null) throw new Error("No file ID.");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(docId);
  var mime = file.getMimeType();
  var format = "";
  var ext = "";
  switch (mime) {
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.document":
      format = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
      ext = ".docx";
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }

  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + docId + "/export?mimeType=" + format;
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "get",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getBlob();
  var filename = file.getName();

  var id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName(~filename.indexOf(ext) ? filename : filename + ext).getId();
  return id;
};

const convertSelection = () => {
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById(ID_TO_COPY)
  let paragraph = doc.getBody().getParagraphs()
  // Copied the second paragraph
  let second_paragraph_text = paragraph[2].getText()
  // Create a new document and copy the content
  let new_doc = DocumentApp.create('temp_to_docx')
  new_doc.getBody().setText(second_paragraph_text)
  let tmp_id = new_doc.getId()
  // Pass the new Document to the function
  let new_id = convertGoogleDocToMicrosoftWordDoc(tmp_id)
  // Remove the temporal document
  DriveApp.removeFile(tmp_id)
  Logger.log(new_id)
}

function getSelection() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById(ID_TO_COPY)
  let paragraph = doc.getBody().getParagraphs()
  // Copied the second paragraph
  let second_paragraph_text = paragraph[2].getText()
  // Create a new document and copy the content
  let new_doc = DocumentApp.create('temp_to_docx')
  new_doc.getBody().setText(second_paragraph_text)
  let tmp_id = new_doc.getId()
  // Pass the new Document to the function
  let new_id =  convertGoogleDocToMicrosoftWordDoc(tmp_id)
  // Remove the temporal document
  DriveApp.removeFile(tmp_id)
  Logger.log(new_id)
}
```

###### Documentation

- [`DocumentApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [`Body Class`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)